# Is it possible to specify which Entity we want to use to create a user?

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm a beginner with Symfony so I still don't know well what's possible or not with this framework.
I created 2 entities with FOSUser, one for societies, and an other for schools. I can create every users I want with the society, but I can't change entities to create school users.

I don't know if my question is dumb but I can't see a way to differentiates these users excepted if I give them roles, plus, I can't find anything about this on Google.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can plugin your own user provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html which will give you the ability to create users with different classes.  Another approach would be to use single table inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance which automatically use the proper class.  Though integrating sti with FOSUserBundle could be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that iIf you use FOSUserBundle, you cannot have multiple user class. The bundle configuration allows you to define a single user class which extends the base user model provided by the bundle.

Based on what I did in many project, I suggest you to have a single User class with the actual user data (i.e. name, username, email, password) and then, in your Society and School class, have a $user property which refers to the User object.